# Group policy result for a list of computers

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy

Is there a PowerShell command that can be run against list of computers to obtain computer policy settings in a domain?

my servers are all windows 2008 and 2012 OS.

I will apply some GP settings to high number of servers and I want to know if I can run PowerShell command against my .txt server list that contains server names  then export to result  html file or text file.

Answer (score 4):

Create your text file as RemoteComputers.txt with each computer/server on its own line...nothing else in the file.

From the admin workstation/server:

1. `Import-Module GroupPolicy`

Then run the script below:

```
$RemoteComputers = Get-Content -Path C:\Data\RemoteComputers.txt

foreach ($computer in $RemoteComputers)
{
Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy -Computer $computer -ReportType htm -Path C:\Data\rsop\$computer.htm
}
```

Comment: thanks, I understand $remotecomputers are my server lists and what does "computer" txt do?

Comment: I modified my answer, was doing two things at once.  $remotecomputers is the array variable you will store the content of remotecomputers.txt into.  You don't have to have the header row unless you have multiple attributes you want to observe, in which case you would use "$computer.Name" or "$computer.IP" etc. in your -Get-GPResultantSetofPolicy -Computer $computer portion.  So if you wanted to report based on IP you could have a csv with name and IP and use $computer.IP in that portion of the script.  The foreach ($computer ...) could be foreach ($rowfromCSV in $RemoteComputers) if you like..